# SQL Error: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql

i have a problem with the next code:

```
create function proc1 (id int)
returns float
begin
    declare sum float
    select sum = (note1+note2+note3)/3 from test1.note where note.id=id;
    return sum;
end
```

I got this error :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select sum = (note.note1+note.note2+note.note3)/3 from test1.note where note.id=' at line 5
```

I've spent much time searching for a solution but no solution was found :(

Comment: You have `declare` and `select` in the same statement. That must be a typo.

Comment: Add a semicolon behind 'declare sum float;'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delimiter |
create function proc1 (id int)
returns float
begin
    declare sum float;
    select (note1+note2+note3)/3 into sum from test1.note where note.id=id;
    return sum;
end
|
delimiter ;
```

You had multiple errors:

- no delimiter defined. Otherwise the DB thinks your function definition stops at the first `;` which is wrong
- you need to use `select ... into`. Otherwise you get a "not allowed to return a resultset from a function" error
- you forgot a semicolon after your `declare`

Answer (score -1):

Use set instead of select or better return without declaring a variable:

```
delimiter //
create function proc1 (id int)
returns float
begin
    return (select (note1+note2+note3)/3 from test1.note where note.id=id);
end
//
delimiter ;
```

or with variable:

```
delimiter //
create function proc1 (id int)
returns float
begin
    declare sum float;
    set sum = (select (note1+note2+note3)/3 from test1.note where note.id=id);
    return sum;
end
//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: What was the reason for the downvote. The use of 'set' or for pointing out that it's not necessary to declare a variable?